# How to repeat the first value of a column until the end of the file in bash?

Tags: bash

I have several files like this:

-400.0  238.963 -6.598192e-07

-399.5     (blankspace)     -3.041492e-07

-399.0      (blakspace) -1.541584e-07

-398.5  (blankspace)    7.299802e-08

-398.0  (blankspace)    1.602192e-07

...

All of them goes until row number 1601.

I want to print the value of the second column until the end of the file.

Like this:

-400.0  238.963 -6.598192e-07

-399.5  238.963 -3.041492e-07

-399.0  238.963 -1.541584e-07

-398.5  238.963 7.299802e-08

-398.0  238.963 1.602192e-07

...

(blankspace) means that it is a column but with no value from row 2 on.

I tried this:

for file in f
do
awk '(NR<=1601) {print $2} $f > test.dat
done

But something is missing.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Comment: I do not see your point. I try to find a question similar to mine and I did not find it. If you do not want to answer it, it is ok. I am not an expert that is why I made this question.

Comment: Apparently you did not read it this time, either.

Comment: If you want to "punish" me for me something I did or did not do, please go straight to the point, cause I am really not understanding.

Comment: You feel "punished" when encouraged to read rules/best practises of a community you are part of?

Comment: @Joana he's tryna tell you that you've got seven questions asked but none of them has an accepted answer, you should choose the best answer given to each question and accept it. to accept an answer simply click the tick beside the answer body. if you don't accept any answers, nobody will answer your questions to come.

Comment: Thanks @oguzismail. I apologize for that.

Comment: @JamesBrown as I told you I wasn't understanding. I will correct my mistake immediately.

Comment: @JamesBrown no changes, an hour later.

Comment: @Rob no changes because I had to leave. I already put the "tick" in every question I made.

Comment: If I had a certain way to prove it I'd agree, you just went in and ticked whatever. Then you've [done the same](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/315873/remove-strings-of-a-filename-and-leave-others-in-bash#comment555307_315875) thing elsewhere, and [it's on us](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55815505/how-to-repeat-the-first-value-of-a-column-until-the-end-of-the-file-in-bash?noredirect=1#comment98297969_55815505) to explain social norms; *this* is what we're saying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk 'NR==1{col2=$2}NR>1{$2=col2 OFS $2}1'  file
```

would do

Explanation :

- `NR==1{col2=$2}` grabs the second column from the first record and stores it to `col2`
- `NR>1{$2=col2 OFS $2}` - From record two onwards, concatenate the grabbed column `col2` to the second field.
- `1` is the most simple command to `awk`. It just prints the record.